# How to add a Page to Frame using code in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a Window where I have put a Frame. I would like to add a Page to the Frame when I click a button that is also on the Window but not in the Frame. There are several buttons in the Window and each click on a button should load a different Page in the Frame.

Since I'm a total newbie on this WPF stuff it's quite possible that this approach is not the best and I have thought about replacing the Frame with a Canvas and then make UserControls instead of Pages that will be added to the Canvas. I welcome any ideas and suggestions on how to best solve this.

I aiming for a functionality that is similar to the application Billy Hollis demonstrated in dnrtv episode 115. (http://dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showID=115).

Comment: Robert: I'm making an app similar to the Billy Hollis app too. Maybe we can share some knowledge.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

the Frame class exposes a method named "Navigate" that takes the content you want to show in your frame as parameter.
try calling

```
myFrame.Navigate(myPageObject);
```

this should work

Comment: this also displays the navigation controls. I prefer to use myFrame.Content=myPageObject;

Answer (score -2):

yourFramName.NavigationService.Navigate(yourPageObject)

e.g 
Frame1.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page1());