# How do I load a page in a Frame in WPF window when i click on a hyperlink

Tags: wpf, hyperlink

I have a problem when I click on a hyperlink.  Page1 should load in frame1 in a WPF window.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138096/how-to-add-a-page-to-frame-using-code-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

I grabbed this example from Adam Nathan's book:

```
<TextBlock>
Click <Hyperlink NavigateUri="page1.xaml">here</Hyperlink> to view the page.
</TextBlock>
```

You can also do this in code:

```
this.NavigationService.Content = nextPage;
```

or

```
this.NavigationService.Source = new Uri("page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```