# Change Set of Elements in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, desktop-application

i had an application that is made using WinForms, in the application every view or page is a panel that contains controls, so the app is one form and many panels, and   when i want to move next or previous i move the current page outside and replace it with the next panel.

The question is, how to do that in WPF? since in windows forms i have panels, i as far as i know there is nothing similar to it in WPF, i tried some ways to mimic the behavior of what i did in the WinForms, but no luck

Comment: Navigation is what it sounds like you want. Microsofts documentation for it is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview). Alternately look into an MVVM framwork like MVVMLight, Caliburn.Micro or Prism.

Comment: WPF has [Pages and Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/138096/60761) but you couls also use UserControls, a TabControl (w/o Headers), ...

Comment: Could any of you add this as an answer, so i  can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was like the following,

- changed the WPF `pages` to `UserControl`
- at the beginning of the application i initialize all the `UserControls`
- load all the `UserControls` in the main form's grid as the following: `MainGrid.Children.Add(UserControl1);` `MainGrid.Children.Add(UserControl2);` ....etc and each `UserControl` has a different location but beside each other
- then on the next or back buttons animate the current page (slide it left or right)